# Codeginiter DB access error

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and whenever I access database that is connected one out of six requests I get the error below. Is this because I request too many times in a short time? I am able to connect database well besides this problem.
I wonder whether there is a time limit on request?

Thank you.

```
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: System error

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php


Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings
```

Comment: take a look at this question, it may help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173104/codeigniter-database-connections-not-being-closed

Answer (score 0):

Is your database setting correct?

hostname:localhost

username:root

password: //Blank in the